# UITextField used for searching UITableView with multiple saved strings

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uisearchbar

In my app, there is component for sending one message to multiple users at the same time.

I would like to implement it similar to facebook message composing. By using uitextfield with local notifications, I'm able to filter my UITableView like this;

```
self.searchTextFieldObserver = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                                    addObserverForName:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                    object:self.searchTextView
                                    queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

                                        if ([self.displayArray count]) {
                                            NSArray *tempUsersArray = nil;
                                            NSArray *tempNonUsersArray = nil;
                                            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fullName CONTAINS[cd] %@", self.searchTextView.text];

                                            self.displayArray = [MyAddressBook sortedContacts:self.contacts];

                                            if ([self.searchTextView.text length] > 0) {
                                                tempUsersArray = [self.displayArray[0] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


                                                self.displayArray = @[tempUsersArray];
                                            }

                                        }

                                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                                    }];
```

This works as expected... As I'm providing input for textfield, my table gets filtered. What I want to implement is this approach:

[image: FBImage]

When I select one user by searching the table view, his nickname should be inserted in my textfield and predicate should be reseted to empty string, so I can start filtering again. Back button should select already inserted name and on second backspace tap, it should delete it.

I was thinking about this for some time, and all I could come up with, was using multiple element on top of each other. UITextView would change it's frame as users are added up (saved in array, which is source for UILabel's text, that partly replaces frame of textview), but I hitted wall, when I had to have possibility of removing already picked users.

If you guys know about another approach, or about any library that could help me, I would be very glad.

Comment: I would use the TextFieldDelegate protocol and not NSNotification center.

Comment: Hmm, but that is just another way of filter the table, right?

Comment: You can look here for a rough start : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=token

Comment: Thanks for advice EPyLEpSY, I'm working with JSTokenField now.. but it is indeed rough :D

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for making this an answer instead of just a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet to comment.

Anyway, I think I would probably have an array of the selected user names that have been added to the textField. Then you could use UIControlEventEditingChanged to check for the text changing, and in that method that gets called take the textField's current text, strip out any strings that match those in the selected user names array as well as commas and such, then set your filter string to what's left over.

As an example of how you could use UIControlEventEditingChanged:

```
[_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

In the case of removing users from the textField, you could use that same textFieldDidChange method to compare the array of added users to the textField, and if one exists in the array that doesn't exist in the textField anymore remove it before re-filtering.

-Stephen

Comment: This is correct, however I needed to have objects in my textfield (entire name tappable) so after tapping it highlights it and cursor disappears however keyboard remains open